# visual studio 2008 loading template problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

i was trying to create a new silverlight solution using visual studio 2008 and am getting the following error:

Error: this template attempted to load an untrusted component 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.

i have installed Silverlight and everything but i wonder why this problem. Also i cant open my existing silverlight applications because then again i get an error saying: "This project type is not supported."

please help.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer to my own problem...so i will share it with you...
what i did was instead of uninstalling everything i just ran the setup for 2008 SP1 again and it sorted out all the problems i was facing...!

thanks.

Comment: you mean "repairing" it, not "reinstalling" it

Answer (score 1):

Check this link , same problem which you are facing, just remove and reinstall vs  :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/e03d0a0e-8a5b-415c-a56d-8f5ebfde46b3